# How to use gacinstall in Inno Setup?

Tags: gac, inno-setup

I expected that this flag should be used together with `dontcopy` - to make sure the files don't get copied anywhere except for GAC. But this combination is invalid as stated by the compiler. So, what's the best practice for `gacinstall`? Actually copy these files to `{app}` anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up copying files to a temporary folder - then installing them to gac with `gacinstall` and ngening them from the `[Run]` section.

Answer (score 2):

The [best practice is to not use the GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498361/when-and-when-not-to-install-into-the-gac).   However, there are [advantages to using the GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-the-gac/23598).

As I see it, you have two valid options for installation.

- Install into {app}  (But then why use the GAC)
- Install into {tmp}