# dll reference - GAC vs Bin

Tags: c#, dll, gac

> I have two project in my visual studio solution project A and project
>   B. Project A deploys its dll into the GAC.  Project B references the
>   dll of project A. Now I would like to know whether I should add the
>   reference of project A from its' bin directory or from GAC, which one
>   is the good practice.

Comment: Maybe this post will help you decide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-the-gac

Comment: @Xcelled194 - good find - I believe that question completely covers OPs concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak for what is best practice, but if it is already deployed to GAC, then it would be the copy used preferentially by the machine, so I would reference that.

Comment: although I would add that if you can avoid deploying project A to the GAC in the first place, do it. Often maintaining the GAC is more trouble than it is worth